# Having issues with my first python web scraper part 2 (The Sequel)

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I am trying to write a web scraper to take information from a database on supreme clothing called supremecommunity.com I made a post about it and it was not working, got some great help, and now it is almost working.

The code works for the most part but it starts having issues after Fall-Winter 17'

This is the error message I got in my Jupiter notebook.

UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     24             upvote = card.select_one('.progress-bar-success > span').get_text(strip=True)
     25             downvote = card.select_one('.progress-bar-danger > span').get_text(strip=True)
---> 26             writer.writerow([item_name,item_image,upvote,downvote])
     27             print(item_name,item_image,upvote,downvote)

~\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0392' in position 0: character maps to

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://www.supremecommunity.com{}'
links = ['https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/fall-winter2011/overview/','https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/spring-summer2012/overview/','https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/fall-winter2012/overview/',
         'https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/spring-summer2013/overview/','https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/fall-winter2013/overview/','https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/spring-summer2014/overview/',
         'https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/fall-winter2014/overview/','https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/spring-summer2015/overview/','https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/fall-winter2015/overview/',
         'https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/spring-summer2016/overview/','https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/fall-winter2016/overview/','https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/spring-summer2017/overview/',
         'https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/fall-winter2017/overview/', 'https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/spring-summer2018/overview/','https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/fall-winter2018/overview/',
         'https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/spring-summer2019/overview/','https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/fall-winter2019/overview/']


with open("supremecommunity.csv","w",newline="") as f:     
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['item_name','item_image','upvote','downvote'])
    for link in links:
        r = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

        for card in soup.select('[class$="d-card"]'):
            item_name = card.select_one('.card__top')['data-itemname']
            item_image = base.format(card.select_one('img.prefill-img').get('data-src'))
            upvote = card.select_one('.progress-bar-success > span').get_text(strip=True)
            downvote = card.select_one('.progress-bar-danger > span').get_text(strip=True)
            writer.writerow([item_name,item_image,upvote,downvote])
            print(item_name,item_image,upvote,downvote)
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using (2.x or 3.x)? Using Python 3.7 on my system, your code ran without any errors.

Comment: I am using 3.7 as well. Did you have values for the 2018 and 2019 seasons? It works for me except for those.

Comment: I just fixed it by adjusting the open csv line                                                                with open("supremecommunity.csv","w", encoding='utf-8',newline="") as f: